# Building a query which sets a column according to the data in a join table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `af` with columns `af.id`, etc. and a table `af_pb` with columns `af_id` and `pb_id` (which assigns entities from table `pb` to the entities of table `af`).

What i want:

- add a new column `precedence` in table `af`
- for each `af.id` in `af`:

  - if there is a pair `(af_id, pb_id)` with `af.id = af_id` and some `pb_id` in the join table `af_pb`, then set `af.precedence = 0`
  - if there is **no** such pair, set `af.precedence = 1`

How can i reach this in PostgreSQL? I already read about the case-when-else-statement but I didn't managed to implement it such that the column `precedence` is set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this can be done in with a `case` expression, it is not necessary. If you want a default value for later inserts into table `af` then alter the table with it, then update to set the non-default.

```
alter table af add column precedence integer default 1; 
update af 
   set precedence = 0 
 where exists (select null 
                 from af_pb 
                where af.af_id = af_pb.af_id);
```

If a default is not desired then a just add the column and afterward update to set the appropriate value:

```
alter table af add column precedence integer;  
update af 
   set precedence = 
      ( not (exists (select null 
                       from af_pb 
                      where af.af_id = af_pb.af_id)))::integer;
```

Comment: …and then possibly add a non-null constraint.